# Restrições de Grupos AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, segurança, active-directory

Estou neste momento desenvolvendo uma *WebAPP* onde já consegui fazer com que o login confirme as credenciais do utilizador no AD. 
Basicamente o login já funciona corretamente. O meu objetivo agora é criar *1 grupo no AD* e especificar que apenas quem estiver nesse grupo pode aceder à aplicação. 
Alguém tem conhecimento de como posso fazer isto ?

```
DllImport("advapi32.dll")] 
public static extern bool LogonUser(string name, string domain, string pass, int logType, int logpv, ref IntPtr pht); 
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
  IntPtr th = IntPtr.Zero; bool log = LogonUser(txt_user.Text, "dominio", txt_pass.Text, 2, 0, ref th);  
  if (log)
 }
```

Comment: é possível inserir mais detalhes na pergunta? Tipo: como está a classe que você realiza o login.

Comment: Fiz várias pesquisas e encontrei este código e até agora esta funcionar. Consegue reconhecer o user e dizer-me se a credenciais estão certas ou erradas. O que me falta agora como disse é as restrições, apenas quem estive no grupo de AD tem acesso à aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei por usar este código super simples e 100% funcional.

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="dominio\grupo" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Você deve utilizar as classes de System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement para tal objetivo:

```
// Obtem o contexto do domínio 
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME");

// Busca o usuário. 
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

// Busca o grupo em questão 
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

if(user != null) 
{ // Verifica se o usuário está no grupo 
    if (user.IsMemberOf(group)) 
    { 
        // Caso positivo, faça alguma coisa 
    } 
}
```

http://www.marcioalthmann.net/2014/02/descobrindo-grupos-autorizacao-usuario-dominio/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/8fd13d9f-a4d4-40ae-997f-eabd5a270af8/como-descobrir-os-usurios-de-um-grupo-do-ad-via-web-part-c?forum=sharepointpt

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029378/how-to-check-if-a-user-belongs-to-an-ad-group